# How to use late binding without the need of Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a function which works fine on my machine if the `Microsoft Office 16 Object Library` is added in the `reference`.
My question is, how do I use `late binding` so that I don't have to add the Microsoft Office 16 Object Library from the list of references.

On my Start up form I have:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
On Error Resume Next
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT CustomerName FROM tblCustomers")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then

MsgBox "Back-end data Not found: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description & " Please locate the data 
file!", , "Data file not found"
Call AttachBackEndFile
End If
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmStartUp"
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMain"
End Sub
```

Function for opening the File Dialog:

```
Public Function AttachBackEndFile() As Boolean
On Error GoTo 0
Dim oFileDialog As FileDialog
Dim result As VbMsgBoxResult
Set oFileDialog = FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
oFileDialog.show

If oFileDialog.SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
result = RelinkTables(oFileDialog.SelectedItems(1))
If result = vbCancel Then
AttachBackEndFile = False
End If
AttachBackEndFile = True
Else
AttachBackEndFile = False
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: See [FileDialog with late binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9477733/77335)

Comment: After reading the two examples. I think I now get it. It looks like the key is to use: `Const msoFileDialogFilePicker As Long = 3` `Dim oFileDialog As Object` `Set oFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)` Then `With oFileDialog .AllowMultiSelect = Fales .Show .... End With` Thanks @HansUp and @June7. You have made life much bearable.